# Convert a mp3 to wav using javascript on a browser

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

How can I convert a .mp3 file to .wav file using javascript on a browser?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot so it using JavaScript, among other reasons simply because it is not allowed to access the file system. If it is supposed to be a web service, upload the file, do the processing on the server, and then let the user downlad it.

Comment: i dont understand what you exactly mean?

Answer (score 2):

**Are you looking for something like this?**

MP3.js - a JavaScript MP3 decoder based on JSMad

MP3.js is a refactored version of JSMad designed to run in ofmlabs Aurora audio framework. It supports all of the features of JSMad and is released under the same GPLv2 license. The code was reorganized a bit, and now uses all typed arrays for decoding at better performance.

https://github.com/devongovett/mp3.js